# rosbag message instance & ros1_bridge help

Tags: ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was working with some tools for ros2 when I came across rosbag and it's message_instace class. On the same topic, I started understanding the ros1_bridge.

I'd like to get more detail on how ros1_bridge understands the message_instance data published by rosbag and converts the same to ros2 format and re-publishes.

Could anyone help me with docs/links or any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288063/rosbag-message-instance-&-ros1_bridge-help/) by [Sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/34246/sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosbag` and `ros1_bridge` are entirely separate tools. They are only connected by the ROS communications infrastructure between them. Messages that `rosbag` replays look like messages published from any other source. The `message_instance` class is no longer relevant once a message has been published by `rosbag`.

If you want to learn how `ros1_bridge` translates messages from ROS 1 to ROS 2, you should start by looking at the [`ros1_bridge` source code](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge). The `dynamic_bridge` creates an object for each mapping between ROS 1 and ROS 2 (and in the other direction). This object stores the topic to subscribe to on the ROS 1 side, the topic to publish to on the ROS 2 side, and a pointer to a callback function. The callback function handles translating each message received. The actual translation of a specific message type is handled by a function that is generated for that message using a templating language (not C++ templates, a Python-based one). You can see the template in `resource/pkg_factories.cpp.em`; look for the `convert_1_to_2` function. Essentially it does a recursive field-wise copy of the message data.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0